# Signals in Linq to Sql?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, django-signals

Does anyone know of a way to do something similar to [Django's `signals`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) using LINQ to SQL?

I'm trying to record when new rows are inserted and when certain columns are updated, so I really just want `pre_save` and `post_save` signals.

I can kind of do it with some models by using the partials defined like `OnFooIDChanging()` and `OnFooIDChanged()` (where `FooID` is a primary key), but this doesn't work for models whose primary key is not an identity, or is set by code.

For those, I could possibly use `OnValidate()`, but that would only be `pre_save`, and it makes dealing with the database tough, since `OnValidate()` is called from `DBContext.SubmitChanges()`, which of course doesn't allow a second `SubmitChanges()` to be called from within, making `post_save` basically impossible as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've gone completely down the rabbit hole on this one, but I think I have a pretty cool solution:

First, add an event handler to your data context that will collect all of the post-save signals and hide the `Dispose` method so that we can call the event right before we dispose. (Note that I use the `new` keyword instead of `override`. This makes calling the event possible.)

```
partial class MyDataContext
{
    internal delegate void PostSaveHandler();
    internal event PostSaveHandler PostSave;

    // This method hides the underlying Dispose because we need to call PostSave.
    public new void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Obviously necessary error handling omitted for brevity's sake
        PostSave();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Next, write a [T4 Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) that inspects the `dbml` file that Linq to Sql generates for you.

```
<#
var dbml = XDocument.Load(@"MyDataContext.dbml");
var name = XName.Get("Type", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007");
var tables = from t in dbml.Descendants(name) select t.Attribute("Name").Value;
foreach(var table in tables)
{
#>
    ...
```

For each table in the database (and thus each partial class), add on to the partial with the following methods.

```
public partial class Foo
{
    internal void OnInsert(MyDataContext db) {
        PreInsert();
        db.PostSave += delegate { PostInsert(); };
    }
    internal void OnUpdate(MyDataContext db) {
        PreUpdate();
        db.PostSave += delegate { PostUpdate(); };
    }
    internal void OnDelete(MyDataContext db) {
        PreDelete();
        db.PostSave += delegate { PostDelete(); };
    }
    partial void PreInsert();
    partial void PostInsert();
    partial void PreUpdate();
    partial void PostUpdate();
    partial void PreDelete();
    partial void PostDelete();
}

// repeat for all tables
```

Also add another `partial MyDataContext` via T4. This will be adding definitions to the partial methods that Linq to SQL gives you (as Merritt mentioned).

```
public partial class MyDataContext
{
    // Add these three partial methods for each table
    partial void InsertFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.OnInsert(this);
        ExecuteDynamicInsert(foo);
    }
    partial void UpdateFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.OnUpdate(this);
        ExecuteDynamicUpdate(foo);
    }
    partial void DeleteFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.OnDelete(this);
        ExecuteDynamicDelete(foo);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hide those files away somewhere safe, so no one tries to mess with them.

Your signals framework is set up. Now you can write your signals. Put these either in `Foo.cs` or all together in a `Signals.cs` file:

```
partial class Foo
{
    partial void PostInsert()
    {
        EventLog.AddEvent(EventType.FooInserted, this);
    }
}
```

This is a bit complex, so if anything doesn't make sense, please leave a comment and I'll do my best to address it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a much easier solution than what I already posted which didn't work anyway: override SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode):

```
partial class MyDataContext
{
     // SubmitChanges() calls this method after inserting default value for param
     public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
     {

          // Pre-Submit Changes

          //Updates            
          for (int changeCounter = 0; changeCounter < this.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count; changeCounter++)
          {                
               var modifiedEntity = this.GetChangeSet().Updates[changeCounter];                
               // Do something, for example:
               // var tableXEntry = new TableX() { Prop1 = "foo" };
               // this.tableXEntries.InsertOnSubmit(tableXEntry );
          }            

          //Inserts            
          for (int changeCounter = 0; changeCounter < this.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count; changeCounter++)            
          {                
               object modifiedEntity = this.GetChangeSet().Inserts[changeCounter];                
               // Do Something
          }


          // Submit Changes
          base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);


          // Post Submit Changes

          //Updates            
          for (int changeCounter = 0; changeCounter < this.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count; changeCounter++)
          {                
               var modifiedEntity = this.GetChangeSet().Updates[changeCounter];                
               // Do something, for example:
               // var tableXEntry = new TableX() { Prop1 = "foo" };
               // this.tableXEntries.InsertOnSubmit(tableXEntry );
          }            

          //Inserts            
          for (int changeCounter = 0; changeCounter < this.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count; changeCounter++)            
          {                
               object modifiedEntity = this.GetChangeSet().Inserts[changeCounter];                
               // Do Something
          }
}
```

With the Entity Framework, I do something similar to what you are trying to do: after I save a entity, I insert a new entry into a different table for auditing purposes (it's a copy of the entity before the changes). there is a SaveChanges() event on the EF entities container (like the data context) that allows you to add to the current context before changes are saved.